# Visual Studio 2010 wants to start project as class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio

sometimes i have problems with the debug. 
I have a solution with some projects (1 WPF application, 1 console application and some libraries - the console application host some services and the wpf application is the client).

If i want debug the client (or the host) visual studio means it can not be started because it is a class library. But after some tries and restarts of Visual Studio i can debug one of the projects without problems!

Is there a solution for this problem?

Mfg

edit#1: i have already set a startup project. If i want to debug the client, the host will be the startup project. If i want to debug the host, the client will be the startup project.

Comment: if i want to debug the host (console app) i start the client with "control+F5" and the host over the context menu -> debug -> start a new instance

Comment: If you open your .sln file in some text editor: is the first included project some library of your host or client?

Comment: The first project listed in the .sln file is a library (used by another library which is used by the client/host app).

Comment: Can you try this answer, because it helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152272/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly/25843029#25843029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Visual Studio 2010 (probably even before that ;)), you can specify multiple startup projects. Just right click on the solution, click **Set Startup Projects** and choose radio button item **Multiple startup projects**. You can now set the Action property to Start (with or without debugging) for all projects you like.

Comment: thanks! i set the 2 startup projects and can debug without problems!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just hitting debug and haven't set a default debug start project, then it will try and debug the current project, which may well be a class library.

Set the default project by right cliking on a project in SOlutions Explorer and Set As StartUp Project.

Comment: i have already set a startup project. So if i want to debug the client, the host will be the startup project and i press "control+f5" to start the host and then right clicking the client project -> debug -> start new instance