# A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly (2)

Tags: c#

> A project with an output type of class library cannot be started
>   directly. In order to debug this project, add an executable project to
>   this solution which references the library project. Set the executable
>   project as the startup project.

While running the program in C# visual studio 2010 I am getting this error. Please tell me how to sort out this error?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you need to do. What are you having difficulty with, precisely?

Comment: The project you've attempted to debug can't be debugged because it's a class library so there is no point of execution.

Do you have any other projects in your solution?

Comment: Well I think you should post this error...

Comment: @PoweRoy at beginning is the error

Comment: Can you try this answer, it helped me! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152272/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly/25843029#25843029

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506185/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Answer (score 68):

Set your startproject in the project explorer by clicking right mouseclick on an executable project and choose "**Set as start project**"

Answer (score 21):

You created the project as a class library project, not an executable program. Class libraries are compiled and then used by other applications for common functionality.

If you meant to create a class library, you need to create a test application (or, better yet, Unit Tests) to test the functionality. If you meant to create an executable application, you'll need to modify the project.

If you have multiple projects in a single solution, you might also need to make sure you have the correct project set as the "Start Project" rather than one of the class library projects.

Comment: Downvote as soon as I posted? Anybody care to comment as to why?

Comment: Same happened for me, I guess someone is trolling here:)

Comment: Seems to happen on answers on some questions. Blanket downvoting for no reason what so ever.

Comment: Upvoted answers here, just for the sake of fending off the troll.

Answer (score 10):

what you have done is that you have made a `class library` with all your code
every project in .Net needs a starting point like `Main()` function in c# which obsly isnt present in a class libraty type of project
what you can do instead is
1. Make a **console project** inside the same solution. by right clicking the solution and add new project
2. Add a reference to the class library
3. Access the classes/methods of the **class library** and then starting the **console project** instead of **class library** project
**Alternatively,** 
If you have a **console project** OR any other project in the solution already
right click the project in the solution explorer and **Set as Startup project**

Comment: I think he may of just not set the startup project. This is stored locally so if he just code the sorce code from someone else it would not be set.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert-really you would downvote for something like this. when this isnt even mentioned in the question? since when giving more(probably correct) info is a reason to down vote

Comment: This answer is hard to read and has a lot of formatting problems.  That is probably why it got a downvote.

Comment: Tried to set current project(code generated from the class diagram) as an executable project and did not have any luck. Follow @ParvSharma solution, and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Right click on Solution-->Go to properties-->Expand Common properties tab-->(On right side) Select Radio button with option Single startup project-->choose project from drop down list.
Enjoy.

Comment: This did it for me, I had 2 projects inside the 1 solution. I just had to choose the other project.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to debug code in the DLL or run it using tests, go to the properties of the project, go to the Debug tab, select "Start external program" and enter the name of the application to use, such as a test runner.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project properties page, change Output Type to `Console Application` or `Windows Application` (depending on what it is).

Make sure that you've got correct project set as startup one (right click -> set as startup project), and that this one is not of type `Class Library`. If your only project in solution is class library, then you need to create some test executable for it.

Answer (score 1):

The same error type i have found in my one of project suddenly which is running in VS 2012 with MVC 4 only. I have run multiple ways to resolve this error, but i have found filly with small change option in Property window of your respective error giving project.
I have went project property window there i have change startup Project from Healpars to Myproject.Then it is working fine.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to learn that you can indeed set some Class Libraries as Startup and run them, IF they contain user controls.  They run in the UserControl TestContainer which allows one to modify properties, etc.  Basically debug at DesignTime, which can be really helpful.  I have about 20 user controls in a single Project.  This way I can run the TestContainer and choose which user control to run and debug.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a function app project that you want to execute then you need to have Azure development tool installed in your visual studio. Please see the below image for more info.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGs5o.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the API in the set as startup project
Right key on the API

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Try to get into your project
And mark the API in the set as a right-key activation project in the API
This should be able to undo the error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it fast just in your project config file add
`XML <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
//other fields
 <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
//other fields
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -3):

select .net core project, then it will start directly with no doubt. Thanks