# solutions wont build after updating visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

My project was working fine before I updated to the new release of VS 2017. After updating, my solutions opens  but wont build and when I try to build, it says that the version of visual studio are not compatible. 
 what can I do? Or does anyone know how to uninstall the update so i can get my solution working again

#### Error message

> A Project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly. In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project,.

Comment: Don't paraphrase the error message. Include the full error message(s) verbatim (as it/they appears in Visual Studio). Also include the type of projects that are causing the error.

Comment: @Igor, this is the full error message from visual studio:A Project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly.

In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project,.

Comment: @Igor, its a Xamarin project

Comment: Mark the correct project as the startup project. Use the right mouse button (context menu) to do so in the solution explorer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742081/1260204

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14506185/1260204)