# Output Type of Class - error when start selenium project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I have Test project in VS 2017. I added selenium drivers by NuGet and when want start project, I have that error

[image: Screen]

I tried use this, but this don't fix my problem.

[image: Screen]

When I'm in project properies, I can't change my Startup object.

[image: Screen]

What can I do with that?

Comment: Run default test class given by project itself, Build and Check.

Comment: Duplicate?
[Have you took a look here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506185/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)