# Debugging Http Trigger Azure Function VS 2019

Tags: azure, function, http, triggers

I'm totally new to Azure development.

I have a solution with multiple Azure function projects.  Each one has an Output Type of Class Library, and each one is set as a startup project.

I created a new Http Trigger Function, and set it as a startup project, but when I press F5, I get an error:  "A project with an output type of Class Library cannot be started directly."  That doesn't make sense, because all of my Azure functions are Output Type Class Library.  (other Azure functions are not Http Trigger Functions)

Comment: can you add NuGet package for Azure Functions:

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.14" />

Comment: @Sajeetharan version 3.0.3 was automatically added by the wizard.

Comment: @Sajeetharan also, Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions version 1.0.0 was added

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506185/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly check if this helps or post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own issue.

Obviously, a normal project with Output Type of Class Library can not start up.  But as an Azure Function, if we add "host start --port 7077" (or some other unique port number) as an Application Argument to the Properties Page under the Debug tab, it will run the Azure Function DLL wrapped in some supporting code resulting in a "Func.exe" command output window.

There's a little bit of magic here, but that's how we got it working so that I can debug it.